# com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException:Packet too long to query

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on mysql and java application
I got requirement to save as many as possible files with some other records in DB. It should support at least 5 million records.

My question is that: Saving this much big records with files is quite difficult and I can get "Packet for query is too large" Exception.

I have to two options:

1. Increase the size of MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET
2. Store the records in limit with some job trigger (for example over 300k records, then split records in limit and save it in different queries,but not exactly sure how I can split the records).

I do not want to increase the size of MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET, as user can enter any amount of records. Let's say we increase the size to accept 500k records but later user sends a million records to insert then again will get same exception.

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Note: 1 lakh = 100.000 - As quite  a few people might not have seen that unit before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution...rather than processing txt file directly I am zipping it first and then send for insertion and it's able to process 5 million records.

Posting here if someone facing same issue then he can try this solution.